# How to restart Android app (/app state) within Espresso test?

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

I'm testing login page - specifically "Autologin" checkbox, so that user being logged-in once, will be automatically logged-in upon reopening the app (by default user should login from scratch).

How can I simulate this behaviour? Is restarting an app is the only way? Can I reset an app somehow to initial screen (as if being restarted), but so that userdata/cookies should be kept?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My initial solution was to close the app by `Espresso.pressBackUnconditionally()` (it is similar to `Espresso.pressBack()` but will not throw an exception when Espresso navigates outside the application or process under test) and to launch activity again: `activityRule.launchActivity(null)`.

However, at the end we came up with more sophisticated solution of relaunching activity within instrumentation:

```
with(activityRule) {
    finishActivity()
    launchActivity(null)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Activity test rule is deprecated.
You can do this using the following code in Kotlin

```
activityScenarioRule.scenario.close() 
ActivityScenario.launch(YourActivity::class.java, null)
```